# nested excel functions with conditional logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just getting started in Excel and I was working with a database extract where I need to count values only if items in another column are unique.

So- below is my starting point:

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C3:C94735,{"Sharable Content Object Reference Model 1.2","Authored SCORM/AICC content","Authored External Web Content"}))

what i'd like to figure out is the syntax to do something like this-

=sumproduct (Countif range1 criteria..., where range2 criteria="is unique value")

Am I getting this right? The syntax is a bit confusing, and I'm not sure I've chosen the right functions for the task.

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe post some sample data with how it is laid out in the worksheet? It would be easier to understand.

Comment: sure, I've updated the post with a pic.

Comment: the screen shot is not the actual table (to protect the sensitive data) but yes countif in this case would use B3..., and it does work.

Comment: I'm sort of testing for duplicates in each column to find the true record count.

Comment: So you're looking in column J to make sure the value is unique. Then in Column B to see if it is one of the values in your formula. Then what?

Comment: I guess this all has to happen at the same time, but the goal is to get a count of multiple items from col B, where col J does not have a duplicate value from the various rows that my count from col B will return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to solve this same problem a week ago.

This method works even when you can't always sort on the grouping column (J in your case).  If you can keep the data sorted, @MikeD 's solution will scale better.

Firstly, do you know the FREQUENCY trick for counting unique numbers? FREQUENCY is designed to create histograms. It takes two arrays, 'data' and 'bins'.  It sorts 'bins', then creates an output array that's one longer than 'bins'.  Then it takes each value in 'data' and determines which bin it belongs in, incrementing the output array accordingly.  It returns the array.  Here's the important part: If a value appears in 'bins' more than once, any 'data' value meant for that bin goes in the first occurrence. The trick is to use the same array for both 'data' and 'bins'. Think it through, and you'll see that there's one non-zero value in the output for each unique *number* in the input. Note that it only counts numbers.

In short, I use this:

```
=SUM(SIGN(FREQUENCY(<array>,<array>)))
```

to count unique numeric values in `<array>`

From this, we just need to construct arrays containing numbers where appropriate and text elsewhere.

In the example below, I'm counting unique days when the color is red and the fruit is citrus:

[image: conditional unique]

This is my conditional array, returning 1 or true for the rows I'm interested in:

```
($A$2:$A$10="red")*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$10,{"orange","grapefruit","lemon","lime"},0))
```

Note that this requires `ctrl-shift-enter` to be used as an array formula.

Since the value I'm grouping by for uniqueness is text (as is yours), I need to convert it to numeric.  I use:

```
MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,0)
```

Note that this also requires `ctrl-shift-enter`

So, this is the array of numeric values within which I'm looking for uniqueness:

```
IF(($A$2:$A$10="red")*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$10,{"orange","grapefruit","lemon","lime"},0)),MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,0),"")
```

Now I plug that into my uniqueness counter:

```
=SUM(SIGN(FREQUENCY(<array>,<array>)))
```

to get:

```
=SUM(SIGN(FREQUENCY(
    IF(($A$2:$A$10="red")*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$10,{"orange","grapefruit","lemon","lime"},0)),MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,0),""),
    IF(($A$2:$A$10="red")*ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$10,{"orange","grapefruit","lemon","lime"},0)),MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,0),"")
)))
```

Again, this must be entered as an array formula using `ctrl-shift-enter`. Replacing SUM with SUMPRODUCT will not cut it.

In your example, you'd use something like:

```
=SUM(SIGN(FREQUENCY(
    IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$3:$C$94735,{"Sharable Content Object Reference Model 1.2","Authored SCORM/AICC content","Authored External Web Content"},0)),MATCH($J$3:$J$94735,$J$3:$J$94735,0),""),
    IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$3:$C$94735,{"Sharable Content Object Reference Model 1.2","Authored SCORM/AICC content","Authored External Web Content"},0)),MATCH($J$3:$J$94735,$J$3:$J$94735,0),"")
)))
```

I'll note, though, that scaling might be a problem on data sets as large as yours. I tested it on larger data sets, and it was fairly fast on the order of 10k rows, but really slow on the order of 100k rows, such as yours.  The internal arrays are plenty fast, but the FREQUENCY function slows down.  I'm not sure, but I'd guess it's between O(n log n) and O(n^2) depending on how the sort is implemented.

Maybe this doesn't matter - none of this is volatile, so it'll just need to calculate once upon refreshing the data. If the column data is changing, though, this could be painful.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming the source data is sorted by the key value [A], start with determining the occurence of the key column

```
B2: =IF(A2=A1;B1+1;1)
```

Next determine a group sum

```
C2: =SUMIF($A$2:$A$9;A2;$B$2:$B$9)
```

A key is unique if its group sum is exactly 1

```
D2: =(C2=1)
```

To count records which match a certain criterium AND are unique, include column D in a `=IF(AND(D2, [yourcondition];1;0)` and sum this column

Another option is to asume a key unique within a sorted list if it is unequal to both its predecessor and successor, so you could find the unique records like

```
E2: =AND(A2<>A1;A2<>A3)
G2: =IF(AND(E2;F2="this");1;0)
```

E and G can of course be combined into one single formula (not sure though if that helps ...)

```
G2(2): =IF(AND(AND(A2<>A1;A2<>A3);F2="this");1;0)
```

resolving unnecessarily nested AND's:

```
G2(3): =IF(AND(A2<>A1;A2<>A3;F2="this");1;0)
```

[image: example]

all formulas in row 2 should be copied down to the end of the list